# Expression.Constant(value, type) type is unknown. How to define the type

Tags: c#, linq

So the problem is 
I have the following line wehre **value** is a string

```
var filterValue = Expression.Constant(value, property.Type);
```

if property.Type is a string everything is fine however the type really could be anything, like a **decimal?**

I dont know how to make this work for all different types
I have this function

```
private static T Parse (string value)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);
}
```

using that I can do this:

```
var newValue = Parse(value);
var filterValue = Expression.Constant(newValue, property.Type);
```

however I would have to know in advance the type , I tried

```
var newValue = Parse(value);
```

but that doesnt work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to know the type at all:

```
object value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.Type).ConvertFromString(value);
var filterValue = Expression.Constant(value, property.Type);
```

The generics approach isn't appropriate (or needed) in this case.

You might want special handling for `null`, though - or simply not allow it (`property.Type`) could be `int?` etc...

Comment: TypeDescriptor is a very useful thing, thanks for this info! :)

Comment: This Answer helped me a lot. thank you